# Sequelize Aggregate count function returns wrong value with where clause

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables in postgresql - Systems and Conditions.
All conditions will have a systemID.
All conditions will have a field 'publishedStatus'

My task is to get all systems with count of associated 'published' Conditions.

Below is my query.

```
const allSystem = await db.System.findAll({
                subQuery: false,
                attributes: ["id", "title", [db.sequelize.fn("COUNT", db.sequelize.col("conditions.systemID")), "conditionsCount"]],
                include: [{
                    model: db.Condition,
                    as: "conditions",
                    attributes: [],
                    where: { publishedStatus: "published" },
                }],
                group: ['System.id', 'conditions.systemID'],
            });
```

When I use the 'where' clause in the 'include' -> Systems with 0 'published' conditions are ignored.

Whereas if I remove the 'where' clause -> Systems with 0 conditions are included. But it includes conditions of all publishedStatus

Results for reference:

```
Background:
System 1 has 10 conditions. 8 published and 2 unpublished
System 2 has 4 conditions. 0 published and 4 unpublished
System 3 has 0 conditions. 0 published and 0 unpublished

Expected Result:
System 1 = 8 conditions
System 2 = 0 conditions
System 3 = 0 conditions

Without Where Clause:
System 1 = 10 conditions
System 2 =  4 conditions
System 3 =  0 conditions

With Where Clause: (Only 1 row is returned)
System 1 = 8 conditions
```

How do I achieve my desired result? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `required: false` to have OUTER JOIN to include empty conditions.

```
const allSystem = await db.System.findAll({
            subQuery: false,
            attributes: ["id", "title", [db.sequelize.fn("COUNT", db.sequelize.col("conditions.systemID")), "conditionsCount"]],
            include: [{
                model: db.Condition,
                as: "conditions",
                attributes: [],
                where: { publishedStatus: "published" },
                required: false  // <-------------
            }],
            group: ['System.id', 'conditions.systemID'],
        });
```